# Eliminating a color with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to eliminate blue color using the following code with OpenCV:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=cv2.imread('//home/ze/Downloads/blue.jpg ')

lower = np.array([0,0,204], np.uint8)
upper = np.array([204,255,255], np.uint8)
mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)

res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask= mask)  

cv2.imshow('Result', res)

k=cv2.waitkey(5) & 0xFF

if k==27:
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

but I'm getting this error:

> OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match (The lower bounary is neither an array of the same size and same type as src, nor a scalar) in inRange

Comment: Theres a space in your path - does your image even load correctly? Check the shape perhaps?

Comment: Your code works for me, opening an image with blue missing. I also changed `cv2.waitKey(5)` to `cv2.waitKey()`, otherwise I think it only awaits input for 5ms. Specifying a wrong path gives the same error as you get, as None does not match the 3-dimensional lower/upper.

Comment: @Zoe - I rolled it back to the previous version, but with 10K rep you probably have the privileges to do that too. (That said I'm not a diamond-mod if you think they should look at things.)

Comment: n-thing the suggestion of "check what the value of `img` is for you', since even the error message implies the mismatch is between it and the lower boundary, and we know the values for the boundaries"

Comment: @millimoose yeah, but when you mod flag edits, mods can only reject the edit if the post hasn't been edited since. If it has, they can't. That's why I didn't roll back; doing so will prevent mods from overriding the approval.

Comment: @Zoe - Fair enough, I'm just not sure why one would wait for the few big mods to handle something the community has an explicit tool and mandate to do anyway.

Comment: @Zoe there was a problem with conflicting edits. I started editing while another edit was being made and it made it look weird. If you look at how it was approved, it actually got rejected as "conflicted with a subsequent edit", but the OP approved it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most likely related to loading the specified image-path. Generally, I plaster my code with these kinds of checks when accessing file-system:

```
img = cv2.imread('/path/that/might/change')
if img is None:
    print("Error loading img")
    sys.exit(-1)
```

I think generally it's a good idea to do these assertions when loading data from external resources, whether over the internet or file-system. Your code runs without a problem when specifying the correct path to an image, other than changing `cv2.waitKey(5)` to `cv2.waitKey()`, or your image will only flash open briefly.